# AWS ECS service creation ( Ec2 Launch type) holding Create IN Progress status and showing Create Failled State after Rollback

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am learning and exploring AWS ECS service by creating cluster, service and task definition (ECS EC2 launch type). And pulling docker image from AWS ECR. Both cluster and task definitions are getting creating successfully. But while creating service, its holding "Create In Progress" state long time and showing Create Failled. And when scrolling down , it also lists Rollback also.

My Docker file looks like the following for helloworld angular application,

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN ng build --configuration production

FROM nginx as runtime
COPY --from=build /app/dist/helloworld/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

**Steps Done  For My Task**

1. Cluster Creation

   1.1 Created cluster with support of Ec2 Launch type
   1.2 Choosing Amazon Linux 2 instance
   1.3 Choosed t2.micro instance type
2. Task Definition

   2.1 Choosed Ec2 launch type
   2.2 Choosed Linux/x86_64
   2.3 .5 vCpu and 1 Gb Memory
   2.4 Choosed my ECR URL for image and mapped to port 80
   2.5 Networ mode awsvpc
3. Service creation

   3.1 Choosed Ec2 Launch type
   3.2 Application type service.
   3.3 Choosed family with created task defintion.
   3.4 Service type replica
   3.4 Choosed Desired no of task 1

**NB** -:It is working sucessfully in ECS Fargate method (By choosing Fargate option in Task definition and Fargate option in service)

**Problem is When I am defining task defintion ec2 launch type and service also Ec2 launch type. If I am choosing Ec2 type in both places , it showing created failled error.
When I am checking CloudWatch Logs its not giving any log.**

**Trouble shooted way,**

1. To cross check roles/permission/policy issues, I created from root user account, but still same response.
2. I created cluster to support fargate/ec2 launch type and created service with fargate (by using application LB and without using application LB) , but still same response
3. Cross checked with memory defined which is exceeding t2.micro instance type
4. Cross checked by defining /path to health check
5. Checked the port mapping and http protocol
6. ECR repository path
7. Security group to allow permissions
8. I cross checked the cluster and task definition which created by defining launch type Ec2.

Can anyone suggest any troubleshooting method or kindly give any guidance to resolve please?

[image]

**Updated Error**

`Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered error in aws ecs`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the logs for the ECS tasks/containers, in CloudWatch Logs, to see if there is any error messages that would point to the issue. If you don't have the task configured to log to CloudWatch logs, then you need to do that before continuing.  You also need to look in the ECS service console at the service and tasks to see if there are any error messages there. CloudFormation is just telling you the deployment failed, you need to go find the details of the error before anyone can really help you.

Comment: Maybe your EC2 instances are in a private VPC, and you need to place them behing a NAT Gateway or specific VPC Endpoints?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why `t2.micro` can't be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `t2.micro` for an ECS task that requires "1 Gb Memory". `t2.micro` is too small for that as it has only 1 Gb of RAM. OS and other processes that run on the instance take large chunk of the 1 Gb available, leaving not enough for the task.

Comment: This comment help me :)

Have a task def with containers required 1vCPU/2GB RAM, using a t2.small EC2 -> provisioned task doesn't even have container :)
Have to upgrade to t2.medium and problem fixed. ;)